# Import Google mbox file into Google using Google APIs

Tags: python, email, google-apps

I am working on a script to migrate from domain X to domain Y using Python Google Apps APIs.

For each account on my domain I need to export the mail from domain X and import it into domain Y.

I see that I can create an mbox file for each user account using the [createMailboxExportRequest](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.apps.audit.service.html) method. I then can download the mbox file(s) when it is ready.

Now how can I get the mbox file back into a Google account on domain Y? I need a solution in Python.

There are methods of migrating using the [Email Migration API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-migration/#migrating_email_messages). This requires a RFC822 format email. I don't believe that is the mbox format.

I would hope there is a method in one of the APIs that can simply import the mbox file that Google exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Audit API you referenced for export is not suitable for use here. From the [ToS](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-api-terms) section 4:

> Email Audit API The Email Audit API is not designed and should not be
>   used for general backup, archival, or journaling purposes. Google
>   reserves the right to prevent a customer from using the Email Audit
>   API in ways that might adversely impact the performance or usability
>   of the Email Audit API.

additionally, when using the Audit API, you do not get message state (read/unread, starred, labels, etc, etc).

You should be looking at Gmail IMAP as the method to connect and export messages. IMAP along with [Google's IMAP extensions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions) provide you access to all of the messages metadata (read/unread, starred, labelled, etc). You can authenticate via [OAuth 2.0 with the Gmail IMAP servers](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol).

Messages extracted via IMAP should be in RFC822 format and ready for submission to the Migration API (along with their metadata).

[Got Your Back (GYB)](https://code.google.com/p/got-your-back) is an open source Python script that uses OAuth (1.0 since 2.0 wasn't out when I wrote it) and Gmail-specific IMAP commands to backup and restore accounts. I used IMAP for the restore portion so that it'd be compatible with consumer Gmail account which don't support migration API. However, it may prove a good reference point for you.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your insight and solution. I look forward to testing this out!